# Digital Audio AWS Add To Cart Form Returns Empty Cart

Tags: amazon-web-services

when using AWS Add To Cart form to purchase digital audio, after continuing on Amazons "Add to Shopping Cart" page I am returned an empty shopping cart.

Example URL:
http://www.amazon.com/gp/aws/cart/add.html?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ5D6U3YO5XIR6ZYQ&AssociateTag=scrip04b-20&ASIN.1=B01BZRALVO&Quantity.1=1

The digital album is visable on this page but when you click continue it returns an empty shopping cart. Is this a bug?

EDIT:
I've tried while being logged in and also while being logged out. I've checked my "MP3 Cart" after clicking continue and that is empty too.

Comment: So can we not use the "Add to cart" form for digital products anymore?